# Download CSV in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am trying to download some model data from a search page to a csv file. Here is the relevant code:

config/application.rb

```
require 'csv'
```

controller

```
  def find_by_registration_date
    @registration_date = params[:registration_date]
    @registrations = Registration.where("DATE(created_at) = ? ", @registration_date)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data Registrations.to_csv(@registrations) }
    end
  end
```

model

```
  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |registration|
        csv << registration.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

EDIT: When I try this I get the error:

```
TypeError in RegistrationsController#find_by_registration_date

can't convert ActiveRecord::Relation into Hash

Rails.root: /home/johnmlocklear/railsApps/nso
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/registration.rb:43:in `to_csv'
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_registration_date'
```

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:137:in `find_by_registration_date'

EDIT: This is so odd. If I do something like:

```
  def find_by_registration_date
    @registrations = Registration.order :first_name 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @registrations.to_csv }
    end
  end
```

...then it works as expected. I'm assuming that one of these methods is returning an array, and another is returning a hash?

Comment: Try renaming the method from `self.to_csv` to `to_csv`. Right now it's a class method, but in the controller you're calling an instance method.

Comment: This does not work. It needs to be an instance method so the search options make it over the method.

Comment: Right, but you're calling all in the method, rendering your AREL query useless. If you want to do it at the class level, accept a collection as a parameter, and call it like `Registration.to_csv(@registrations)`

Comment: See edit above. I get the error can't convert ActiveRecord::Relation into Hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with...

app/views/registrations/find_by_registration_date.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Export CSV', csv_path(registration_date: @registration_date) %>
```

routes.rb

```
  match 'csv' => 'registrations#export_csv', :as => :csv
```

app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
  def export_csv
    @registration_date = params[:registration_date]
    @registrations = Registration.where("DATE(created_at) = ? ", @registration_date)
    csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << ["last_name", "id"]
       @registrations.each do |r|
         csv << [r.last_name, r.student_id]
       end
     end
     send_data(csv, :type => 'test/csv', :filename => 'add_hoc.csv')
  end
```

Goes against the 'skinny controller/fat model' paradigm, but works for now.